# DataFrame To Excel in C#

Tags: c#, .net, dataframe, .net-core

I am new to .NetFramWork, I have some Python experience
I have seen that Microsoft is providing DataFrame functionality in  Microsoft.Data.Analysis Nugget Package
I am happy with that, I can see that we can read data from the excel like below

```
DataFrame csvDataFrame = DataFrame.LoadCsv("path/to/file.csv");
```

Any one know how to write DataFrame to the excel, I could not see any method for that
and could you also point me out to documentation on this

Comment: By "write to the Excel" do you mean write a CSV file?

Comment: Yes, to either CSV or Xlsx, or if possible to both

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest to use another library for that. For example, **ClosedXML** (Documentation is [here](https://closedxml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)) which can be installed as NuGet package. And you may do something like this:

```
var csvDataFrame = DataFrame.LoadCsv("path/to/file.csv");

var workbook = new XLWorkbook();
workbook.Worksheets.Add("Test");
var ws = workbook.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault();

var rowNumber = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < csvDataFrame.Rows.Count(); i++)
{
    var row = csvDataFrame.Rows[i];
    var colNumber = 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < row.Count(); j++)
    {
        var cell = ws.Cell(rowNumber, colNumber);
        cell.Value = row[j];
        colNumber++;
    }
    rowNumber++;
}
```

There are also some useful packages for CSV, but approach is the same as for Excel.